# Back end node.js can't receive the data from the front end with Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm building an app that fetch the data form the database in the back end and send the data to the front end page. The command of the required data is input from the front end and then pass to the back end to let the back end fetch the required data form the database. But when the front end POST the command to the back end, NODE console shows:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

And the front end browser console shows:

```
POST http://localhost:5050/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

The GET method works fine. So the logic between back end and database should be just fine and I think could it be the issue with the POST url? I test it for hours and still can't fix it. Please help! Thanks in advance!

---

front end code script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
            chart: {
                    renderTo: containerSpline,
                    type: 'spline'
                },
            title: {
                text: '信息录入统计曲线图'
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: '时间'
                },
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: '数量'
                }
            },
            series: []
    };

    $.get("//localhost:5050", (data)=>{
        // feed the data into the chart
        var series = {
            name:'', 
            data: []
            };
        var xAxis = {
                categories: []
            };
        data.recordset.forEach((item)=>{
            series.data.push(item.Count);
            series.name = item.Dates;
            options.xAxis.categories.push(item.Times);
        })
        options.series.push(series);
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options); 
    })

    $('button').click(()=>{
        var obj = {
            year: $('#year').val(),
            month: $('#month').val(),
            day: $('#day').val()
        }
        console.log(obj);
        $.post('//localhost:5050',JSON.stringify(obj), (text)=>{
            console.log(text); 
        })
    })
})
```

back end code fetchData.js:

```
var express=require('express');
var http = require('http');
var sql=require('mssql');
var fs = require('fs');
var hbs = require('hbs');
var cors = require('cors');
var app=express();
var data;
//config for your database
var config={
        user:'elims',
        password:'abc123@ksd',
        server:'192.168.5.237',   
        database:'ELIMSDB'
    };
    //connect to your database
sql.connect(config,function (err) {
  if(err) console.log(err);
    //create Request object
  var request=new sql.Request();
  var fDate, lDate;
  fDate = '2017-08-04';
  lDate = '2017-08-05';
  request.input('firstdate', sql.NVarChar, fDate);
  request.input('lastdate', sql.NVarChar, lDate);
  request.query(" EXEC dbo.KSD_Front_YbidCountByMinutes @firstdate , @lastdate ", (err,recordset) => {
                      if(err) console.log(err);
                    //send records as a response
                      data = JSON.stringify(recordset);
                    });
  });
// send the data to the script.js
app.use(cors());
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/json;charset=utf-8'});
    res.end(data);
});
app.post('/', (req, res)=>{
  var text = 'Back end response!'
  console.log(req.params.obj);
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/json;charset=utf-8'});
  res.send(text);
})
app.listen(5050,function(){
  console.log('Server is running!');
});
```

Comment: `res.end(data);` is this a typo?

Comment: `'Content-Type':'text.json;charset=utf-8'` you mean `'Content-Type':'text/json;charset=utf-8'` perhaps? although, "Back end response!" isn't JSON so the client may complain

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry about that. I changed it to text/json  and the node console shows error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: @Ofisora I think the issue probably is in the POST method. res.end(data) in the GET method works just fine in  my case.

Comment: well, the code in the question isn't your full code, is it? I mean, the `app.get` sends `data` which is never anything but undefined, so I'm guessing you've "trimmed the code" a bit for the question, perhaps?

Comment: @JaromandaX I actually have all the code here. It's just not the final code for my app because I'm still testing the interaction between the front and and back end. the data in the app.get actually fetch the data from database and send it to the front page to feed in the chart in the front page. $GET in the script.js shows that logic.

Comment: Instead of `text/json` , can you put `application/json` since it is the official MIME type for json?

Comment: oops, @Zachary, didn't see `data = JSON.stringify(recordset);` my bad

Comment: @Ofisora I tried application/json, the error is still: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: @Ofisora I removed the res.Writehead in the POST method. Then no error occur, but the result of console.log(res.params) in the NODE console is still undefined

Comment: `response.writeHead` can only be called **once** on a message - perhaps `cors` uses writeHead?

Comment: @JaromandaX YES man! I remove the res.Writehead in the POST method and no error occurs and the browser even get the test message. BUT the node console still show that the res.params is undefined

Comment: You aren't setting any params in the request

Comment: Instead of `$.post('//localhost:5050',JSON.stringify(obj),..` put params like this `$.post('//localhost:5050', { obj: JSON.stringify(obj)},...`.